# How to download only particular folder files of sub-folders from FTP site in command line in linux

Tags: linux, command-line, ftp, shell-script, wget

I had tried using this command

"wget -r ftp://ftptrace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/giab/ftp/data/AshkenazimTrio/HG004_NA24143_mother/NIST_HiSeq_HG004_Homogeneity14572558/HG004_HiSeq300x_fastq/140818_D00360_0046_AHA5R5ADXX/Project_RM8392/Sample_4A1/"

but in this case it takes huge time and morover it download all the folders starting from ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov - Sample_4A1. So, in this case whether there is any other commands or way to download only particular folder? In my mycase i wish to fetch (download) only this last folder files "Sample_4A1"
is there any script or command to do this? So, by doing this I can make download my required folder by excluding other unnecessary folders files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since it is an FTP server, use an FTP client (`ftp`,`lftp`...) with which you can list files and then issue FTP transfer commands for each?

Comment: @xenoid sorry i couldn't understand. could you please explain  how to do it